# What's wrong in trying to show location on gmap

Tags: java, google-maps, primefaces, xhtml

I want to get coordinates from the DB and show them on a map with a marker but I can't. I think the problem is in the xhtml file. It just have to show the last data stored in the DB. The problem is that the data are being got, and if I insert the location manually, the map show the center without the marker. So I think there's nothing to do with API key, but I'm trying to get the coordinates from gadoBean.java(managedBean) and the map is gray. Please, someone give me a hand.

View:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?Sensor=false"
type="text/javascript"></script>
</h:head>
<title>Rastreamento</title>
<h:body>
 <h:form>
   <p:poll interval="10"
           listener="#{gadoBean.obterPosicaoTag}"
           update="panelMap"/>
<p:panel id="panelMap">
<p:gmap id="mapa"  

        center="#{gadoBean.center}" 
        zoom="18" 
        model="#{gadoBean.mapa}"  
        type="HYBRID" 
        style="width:600px;height:400px"/>
    </p:panel>
    </h:form>  
</h:body>
</html>
```

GadoBean:

```
package com.sisRastrbov.controller;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.faces.model.SelectItem;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;

import com.sisRastrbov.model.Coordenadas;
import com.sisRastrbov.model.Fazenda;
import com.sisRastrbov.model.Gado;
import com.sisRastrbov.model.Tag;
import com.sisRastrbov.model.Usuario;
import com.sisRastrbov.repository.CoordenadasRep;
import com.sisRastrbov.repository.Usuarios;
import com.sisRastrbov.repository.fazendasRep;
import com.sisRastrbov.security.AuthenticationService;
import com.sisRastrbov.services.CoordenadasService;

import org.primefaces.model.map.Circle;
import org.primefaces.model.map.DefaultMapModel;
import org.primefaces.model.map.LatLng;
import org.primefaces.model.map.MapModel;
import org.primefaces.model.map.Marker;

@Named
@ViewScoped
public class GadoBean implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private MapModel mapa;
private Marker marcador = null;
private Circle circulo = null;
private Tag tag;
private Gado gadoAtual;
private float lastLat, lastLong;
private Coordenadas coordenadas;
private List<Coordenadas> posicoes;
private Fazenda fazendaAtual;
private List<Fazenda> fazendas;
private Usuarios usuarios;
private String center;


@Inject
private CoordenadasService coordenadasService;

@Inject
private CoordenadasRep coordenadasRep;

public String getCenter() {
    return center;
}

public void setCenter(String center) {
    this.center = center;
}

private void limpar() {
    coordenadas = new Coordenadas();

}
//<p:commandButton value="Rastrear" id="botaoRastrear" action="# {gadoBean.obterPosicaoTag}" update="mapa"/>
public GadoBean(){
    mapa = new DefaultMapModel();
}
public void inicializar() {

}

public void salvar() {

    coordenadasService.salvar(coordenadas);
    limpar();

}
public void obterPosicaoTag() {
    posicoes = new ArrayList<Coordenadas>();
    posicoes = coordenadasRep.listar();
    int totalPosicoes = this.getPosicoes().size(); //obtem o total de   registros contidos na tabela Coordenadas.
    if (totalPosicoes > 0) {
        Coordenadas posicaoAtual = this.getPosicoes().get(totalPosicoes -  1);//posicao atual recebe sempre a última posição registrada
        LatLng coord = new  LatLng(posicaoAtual.getPosLongitude(),posicaoAtual.getPosLatitude());//coord  recebe o ponto.
        lastLong =(float)posicaoAtual.getPosLongitude();//recebem as coordenadas.
        lastLat = (float)posicaoAtual.getPosLatitude();
        center = lastLat + "," + lastLong;


        System.out.println(center);

        if (circulo == null) {//cria um circulo verde em volta do ponto 
            circulo = new Circle(coord, 15);
            circulo.setStrokeColor("#00ff00");
            circulo.setFillColor("#00ff00");
            circulo.setStrokeOpacity(0.5);
            circulo.setFillOpacity(0.5);
            mapa.addOverlay(circulo);
        } else {
            circulo.setCenter(coord);
        }
        if (marcador == null) {
            marcador = new Marker(coord);
            mapa.addOverlay(marcador);
        } else {
            marcador.setLatlng(coord);
        }

    } else {
        tag = null;
    }
}

public Marker getMarcador() {
    return marcador;
}

public MapModel getMapa() {

    return mapa;
}

public void setMapa(MapModel mapa) {
    this.mapa = mapa;
}

public Fazenda getFazendaAtual() {
    return fazendaAtual;
}

public void setFazendaAtual(Fazenda fazendaAtual) {
    this.fazendaAtual = fazendaAtual;
}

public void setMarcador(Marker marcador) {
    this.marcador = marcador;
}

public Circle getCirculo() {
    return circulo;
}

public void setCirculo(Circle circulo) {
    this.circulo = circulo;
}

public Tag getTagAtual() {
    return tag;
}

public void setTagAtual(Tag tagAtual) {
    this.tag = tagAtual;
}

public float getLastLat() {
    return lastLat;
}

public void setLastLat(float lastlat) {
    this.lastLat = lastlat;
}

public float getLastLong() {
    return lastLong;
}

public void setLastLong(float lastlong) {
    this.lastLong = lastlong;
}

public List<Coordenadas> getPosicoes() {
    return posicoes;
}

public void setPosicoes(List<Coordenadas> posicoes) {
    this.posicoes = posicoes;
}
public Coordenadas getCoordenadas() {
    return coordenadas;
}

public void setCoordenadas(Coordenadas coordenadas) {
    this.coordenadas = coordenadas;
   }




}
```

Coordenadas:

```
package com.sisRastrbov.model;

import java.io.Serializable;

import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;
@Entity
@Table(name = "Coordenadas")
public class Coordenadas implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private Long id;
// Gado gado_id;
private double posLatitude;
private double posLongitude;
private Date posData;
private Tag tag;



@Id
@GeneratedValue
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "tag_id", nullable = false)
public Tag getTag() {
    return tag;
}

public void setTag(Tag tag) {
    this.tag = tag;
}

/*@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "gado_id", nullable = false)
public Gado getGado_id() {
    return gado_id;
}*/

/*public void setGado_id(Gado gado_id) {
    this.gado_id = gado_id;
}*/

@Column(name = "pos_latitude")
public double getPosLatitude() {
    return posLatitude;
}

public void setPosLatitude(double posLatitude) {
    this.posLatitude = posLatitude;
}
@Column(name = "pos_longitude")
public double getPosLongitude() {
    return posLongitude;
}

public void setPosLongitude(double posLongitude) {
    this.posLongitude = posLongitude;
}

@Column(name = "pos_data")
public Date getPosData() {
    return posData;
}

public void setPosData(Date posData) {
    this.posData = posData;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Coordenadas other = (Coordenadas) obj;
    if (id == null) {
        if (other.id != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!id.equals(other.id))
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

}

Tag:

```
package com.sisRastrbov.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
 import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;
import javax.persistence.Table;




@Entity
@SequenceGenerator(name = "tag_sequence", sequenceName = "tag_sequence")
@Table(name = "tag")
public class Tag implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private Long tagId;
private char tagStatus;
private String descricao;

List<Coordenadas> posicoes;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator =  "tag_sequence")
@Column(name = "tag_id")
public Long getTagId() {
    return tagId;
}

public void setTagId(Long tagId) {
    this.tagId = tagId;
}

@Column(name = "tag_status")
public char getTagStatus() {
    return tagStatus;
}

public void setTagStatus(char tagStatus) {
    this.tagStatus = tagStatus;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((tagId == null) ? 0 : tagId.hashCode());
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Tag other = (Tag) obj;
    if (tagId == null) {
        if (other.tagId != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!tagId.equals(other.tagId))
        return false;
    return true;
}

public String getDescricao() {
    return descricao;
}

public void setDescricao(String descricao) {
    this.descricao = descricao;
}
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "tag")
public List<Coordenadas> getPosicoes() {
    return posicoes;
}

public void setPosicoes(List<Coordenadas> posicoes) {
    this.posicoes = posicoes;
}


}
```

CoordenadasRep:

```
package com.sisRastrbov.repository;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityTransaction;
import javax.persistence.Query;

import com.sisRastrbov.model.Coordenadas;



public class CoordenadasRep implements Serializable{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Inject
private EntityManager manager;

public Coordenadas guardar(Coordenadas coo) {
    return coo = manager.merge(coo);
}



public List<Coordenadas> listar(){
    List<Coordenadas> coords = new ArrayList<Coordenadas>();
    coords = manager.createQuery("from Coordenadas",   Coordenadas.class).getResultList();
    return coords;
}
}
```